# Dictionary doesn't find value when using new object as key

Tags: c#, dictionary, hash, hashmap

In Unity 3D, I am trying to build a Dictionary of PathNodes keyed by NodeCoordinates. I have overridden GetHashCode in NodeCoordinate and it should return a constant unique value. If I loop through the keys of the dictionary, the lookup works fine, but if I create a new NodeCoordinate with the coordinates of a PathNode that should exist, the lookup fails even though the hash codes are equal.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PathNode : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Dictionary<NodeCoordinate, PathNode> pathNodes;

    public PathNode left;
    public PathNode right;
    public PathNode forward;
    public PathNode backward;

    private NodeCoordinate coord;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (PathNode.pathNodes == null)
        {
            PathNode.pathNodes = new Dictionary<NodeCoordinate, PathNode>();
        }

        NodeCoordinate coord = new NodeCoordinate(transform.position.x, transform.position.z);
        this.coord = coord;
        PathNode.pathNodes.Add(coord, this);

        NodeCoordinate leftChord = new NodeCoordinate(coord.x - 1, coord.z);
        NodeCoordinate rightChord = new NodeCoordinate(coord.x + 1, coord.z);
        NodeCoordinate forwardChord = new NodeCoordinate(coord.x, coord.z + 1);
        NodeCoordinate backwardChord = new NodeCoordinate(coord.x, coord.z - 1);

        if (PathNode.pathNodes.ContainsKey(leftChord))
        {
            this.left = PathNode.pathNodes[leftChord];
            this.left.right = this;
        }
        if (PathNode.pathNodes.ContainsKey(rightChord))
        {
            this.right = PathNode.pathNodes[rightChord];
            this.right.left = this;
        }
        if (PathNode.pathNodes.ContainsKey(forwardChord))
        {
            this.forward = PathNode.pathNodes[forwardChord];
            this.forward.backward = this;
        }
        if (PathNode.pathNodes.ContainsKey(backwardChord))
        {
            this.backward = PathNode.pathNodes[backwardChord];
            this.backward.forward = this;
        }
    }

    private static bool debug = true;

    void Update()
    {
        if (debug)
        {
            foreach (NodeCoordinate coord in PathNode.pathNodes.Keys)
            {
                Debug.Log(coord + " : " + PathNode.pathNodes[coord] + " : " + coord.GetHashCode());
            }

            foreach (PathNode node in PathNode.pathNodes.Values)
            {
                NodeCoordinate leftChord = new NodeCoordinate(node.coord.x - 1, node.coord.z);
                PathNode leftNode;
                Debug.Log("Left: " + leftChord + " : " + PathNode.pathNodes.TryGetValue(leftChord, out leftNode) + " : " + leftChord.GetHashCode());
            }

            debug = false;
        }
    }
}

public class NodeCoordinate
{
    public float x;
    public float z;

    public NodeCoordinate(float x, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public bool Equals(NodeCoordinate coord)
    {
        return (this.x == coord.x && this.z == coord.z);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}x{1}", this.x, this.z).GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Coordinate: " + this.x + " x " + this.z;
    }
}
```

This is the output from my little debug:
[debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVSKb.png)

As you can see, when looping through the keys, the lookups with hashcodes 2137067561 and 1824497336 work, but when I instantiate a new NodeCoordinate and try to look it up, it has the same hashcode but the lookup fails. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `NodeCoordinate` class doesn't define equality in a way that the dictionary would use. You have a method like this:

```
public bool Equals(NodeCoordinate coord)
```

... but you neither override `IEquatable<NodeCoordinate>` nor do you override `Equals(object)`.

Personally I'd suggest doing both - and implementing a simpler hash code that doesn't require string formatting:

```
public sealed class NodeCoordinate : IEquatable<NodeCoordinate>
{
    public float X { get; }
    public float Z { get; }

    public NodeCoordinate(float x, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Z = z;
    }

    public override Equals(object other) => Equals(other as NodeCoordinate);

    public bool Equals(NodeCoordinate coord) =>
        coord != null && this.X == coord.X && this.Z == coord.Z;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 23;
        hash = hash * 31 + X;
        hash = hash * 31 + Z;
        return hash;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"Coodinate: {X} x {Z}";
}
```

(Note that I've also made it immutable and used properties instead of public fields. I've used C# 6 syntax for simplicity, but it wouldn't be hard to translate to C# 5 if necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason, when I add a IEqualityComparer with the exact same logic, it works.

Changed the declaration of the dictionary to this:

```
if (PathNode.pathNodes == null)
        {
            PathNode.pathNodes = new Dictionary<NodeCoordinate, PathNode>(new NodeCoordinateComparer());
        }
```

Added this:

```
public class NodeCoordinateComparer : IEqualityComparer<NodeCoordinate>
{
    public bool Equals(NodeCoordinate a, NodeCoordinate b)
    {
        return (a.x == b.x && a.z == b.z);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(NodeCoordinate coord)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}x{1}", coord.x, coord.z).GetHashCode();
    }


}
```

Comment: My answer explains the "for some reason". Basically the dictionary doesn't know how to use your `Equals` method.

Comment: Your equals should be : a.Equals(b).  The hash will do the comparison.  Right now you equals is comparing numbers while the hash is comparing strings which may being causing the failure.